# Text not wrapping in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been experimenting with CSS Grid and am stuck on finding the most effective means to have text wrap around a `<div>` element that is positioned partially on-top of two other `<div/>` elements. Basically, like in the image below, I want the text in the red and blue divs to wrap around the yellow div that has been partially positioned in the columns and rows of the other two elements. Obviously, this is a Grid based layout, so I'm not interested in doing this with typical floats. How can I use CSS Grid to achieve this effect?

[image]

Here is my css and html:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="red">According to the Oxford English Dictionary, hello is an alteration of hallo, hollo,[1] which came from Old High German "halâ, holâ, emphatic imperative of halôn, holôn to fetch, used especially in hailing a ferryman."[5] It also connects the development
    of hello to the influence of an earlier form, holla, whose origin is in the French holà (roughly, 'whoa there!', from French là 'there').[6] As in addition to hello, halloo,[7] hallo, hollo, hullo and (rarely) hillo also exist as variants or related
    words, the word can be spelt using any of all five vowels.[8][9][10]</div>
  <div class="blue">The use of hello as a telephone greeting has been credited to Thomas Edison; according to one source, he expressed his surprise with a misheard Hullo.[11] Alexander Graham Bell initially used Ahoy (as used on ships) as a telephone greeting.[12][13]
    However, in 1877, Edison wrote to T.B.A. David, the president of the Central District and Printing Telegraph Company of Pittsburgh: Friend David, I do not think we shall need a call bell as Hello! can be heard 10 to 20 feet away. What you think? Edison
    - P.S. first cost of sender & receiver to manufacture is only $7.00.[14] By 1889, central telephone exchange operators were known as 'hello-girls' because of the association between the greeting and the telephone.[13][15] By 1889, central telephone
    exchange operators were known as 'hello-girls' because of the association between the greeting and the telephone.[13][15] </div>
  <div class="yellow">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If a grid cell is included in two grid elements it doesn't mean the content of one of them will have priority and create a gap in the other one. They will simply overlap. You're looking for the [CSS exclusions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-exclusions/) module, which is currently implemented only in IE 10+ and Edge and is an upgrade of floats.

Comment: so basically if i want to achieve this layout in chrome or firefox i'm stuck with floats still? that's disappointing.

Comment: Although a technology that is still in its infancy (and as a result barely supported), [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) aims to solve exactly your problem and more

Comment: @feihcsim, `shape-outside` currently works with [CSS shapes](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes-2/) and there is no sign it will ever be compatible with CSS grids, while CSS exclusions, most likely, will be.

Comment: Floats are designed for wrapping text around objects, but have been widely misused as a hack for layout design. CSS Grid is designed for layout design, but is now going to be used as a hack for wrapping text around objects?

Comment: i don't see this as a hack for wrapping text, but a legitimate layout option that is limited by the current potential of the grid spec. having css exclusions or something like grid-text-wrap would open up considerable design options, particularly in magazine/newspaper layout.

Comment: @Dog, fair enough. It would certainly be a cool feature to have in Grid Layout. Maybe in a future version.

Comment: I can't find it at the moment, but I am fairly sure I remember hearing [Jen Simmons](http://jensimmons.com/), in one of her youtube videos about css grids (which I highly recommend, if you haven't seen them yet, she is extremely good at teaching that content), that as of css-grids recommendation level one, L shaped grids are not yet possible, but would possibly be in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [exclusions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-exclusions/), but these are only supported by Microsoft's Internet Explorer and Edge and should be used with caution (for now, we have to prefix properties with `-ms-` for exclusions to work, but that doesn't always end in  success).  In a nutshell, an exclusion is an area around an element that inline flow content wraps around.

An element becomes an exclusion when its wrap-flow property has a computed value other than auto, so an example might be `.p { wrap-flow: maximum }`.  The `wrap-margin` property sets the margin or offset surrounding the exclusion area.In your case, you could put `.yellow { wrap-flow: both }` in your CSS to allow the text in the other divs to wrap around the yellow div.

Example of `wrap-flow: both`

[image]

Links: [Tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css-exclusions--cms-28087), [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-exclusions), [specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-exclusions-1/), [tutorial](http://galjot.si/css-exclusions)

Related Tags: [html](/questions/tagged/html) [css](/questions/tagged/css) [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) [css-grid](/questions/tagged/css-grid)