# CSS Grid can I place a column above another column

Tags: css, css-grid

I created a blog layout CSS grid

```
grid-template-columns: 10fr 2fr 18fr 3fr 18fr 3fr 2fr 3fr 18fr 3fr 18fr 2fr 10fr;
```

and created three areas

```
.area-content {
    grid-column: 5 / 10;
}

.area-pull-left {
    grid-column: 3 / 6;
}

.area-pull-right {
    grid-column: 9 / 12;
 }
```

Now I tried to float text around a image (pull-right or pull-left) via this code

```
 <div class="area-content">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do       
     eiusmod tempor incidid
  </div>
  <div class="area-pull-right"></div>
```

But the result looked like this

[image]

is there a way to position the image-column above the content column so that the result looks like this ?

Here is a fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/38gjosss/2/

[image]

The only option I found was to break the content in three parts which isn't helpful at all:

```
<div class="area-content">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
   eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
</div>
<div class="area-content-left">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
   eiusmod tempor incidid
 </div>

 <div class="area-pull-right"></div>
 <div class="area-content">
     ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute    
     irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
 </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48031648/3597276

Comment: thnx! to bad it doesn't work..

Comment: NO, this is not possible using CSS-Grid natively. Grid Areas etc are always rectangular so you can't wrap text around them. Seems to me you are looking for `shape-outside` - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/