# Floating elements in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-float, css-grid

I'm currently working on my first page where I want to use CSS grid `display: grid`.

It works very well, but I come across a small problem with an element that I want `float` classically - text floats around an image, a quote etc.

I simply gave an element a `float: left` and to my surprise, the `float` is completely ignored. The element remains as a full "grid-row-item".

**Short code example:**

```
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% 5% 1fr 5% 5%;
}

main > * {
  grid-column: 3;
}

blockquote {
  grid-column: 2 / -2;
}

blockquote.float-left {
  grid-column: 3;
  float: left;
}
```

*For a larger example, I've created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQWPWX).*

Unfortunately, I have not found anything about this, so my questions are: Has anyone a solution for this? Have I overlooked something? Or maybe that's not possible yet?

Thank you in advance! :)

**Codepen-Link:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQWPWX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't float grid items. Doing so would interfere with the grid layout completely.

If you want to float elements, either remove them from the grid layout, assign `display: grid` to some other intermediate element, or don't use grid layout.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock for the quick answer! I've already thought something like that.

A possibility for a float at this point would make sense in my point of view - or better actually be "the origin" of it. But if it is not intended, other options must be found as a solution. :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 26):

There is actually one solution, use:

```
float: left; in grid works as => justify-self: start;
float: right; in grid works as => justify-self: end;
```

Comment: When I looked this up, I was aware you cannot float in a grid but I did not know what else to call it. This answer is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 6):

Floats are respected on grid containers, but they are completely ignored on grid items.

This behavior is defined in the CSS Grid spec in this section:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-containers

The problem has been discussed here, but has no solution yet:

- [Text not wrapping in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48031648/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the effect you want but it does involve putting in a little extra mark-up. Since the grid affects only the immediate child elements you can put the content you want floated (image, blockquote etc) and the text you wanted to flow around it into a separate div nested inside the container where display:grid is applied.

For example:

```
<div class="playerinfo">
    <div class="content">
        <img class="floatleft" src="images/kane-williamson-sml.jpg" alt="Kane Williamson">
        <p> Kane Stuart Williamson (born 8 August 1990) is a professional cricketer from New Zealand who currently plays as a batsman for Northern Districts in New Zealand domestic cricket, the Sunrisers Hyderabad in theIPL, and New Zealand internationally. He made his first-class debut in December 2007 and his IPL debut in 2015.[1] He made his U-19 debut against the touring Indian U-19 team in 2007 and was named captain of the New Zealand U-19 team for the 2008 U-19 Cricket World Cup. Williamson also represented New Zealand at the ICC Cricket World Cup 2011 hosted by Subcontinental nations and the ICC Cricket World Cup 2015 hosted by New Zealand and Australia. On 14 August 2013, Williamson signed for Yorkshire for the rest of the English county season. On February 16 2015, Sunrisers Hyderabad signed Williamson in the IPL for US$96,500.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using this CSS works well.

```
.playerinfo{
    display: grid;
}
    
.floatleft {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```